# Simple GUI to display static text informations

Tags: software-recommendation, application-development, gui, programming

I would like to know if there is a way to write or modify a simple program (I don't really care what language it'll use) that can be launched in **GUI mode** and will display **formated text** and **URL** that will open in a web-browser by a simple clic.

A good example of the program I would like to run is the "About - Information" window that can be found on most programs, example :

[image: disk "About" window]

It has everything I look for :

- Simple windows using same theme as the DE
- No menu
- Possibility of displaying images
- Formated text (bold, italic, font-size)
- URL links with custom clickable name
- Buttons (*that one is not really important, it could be usefull but I'm afraid it's too hard to configure "actions" for my level in development*)

---

My idea would be going for something like that (where orange is a URL link) :

[image]

Note : I just drew that, it isn't an existing program.

---

I unfortunately don't have time to learn a developer language like C++, Python, QT, but I can examine a file with gedit (or alike) and adapt the content, that shouldn't be really difficult as I have experience on looking at configuration files and modifying them, you know, to see what would happen if I change this or that.

Are there any prebuilt code I could use and/or modify ?

Thanks

*PS: HTML would have been great but apparently there's no easy way to achieve this, nor prebuilt "html interpretator non web-browser" I could use.*

Comment: Can't you just use an existing browser, like [Midori](http://midori-browser.org/), which has an `-a` app option, or [SeaMonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org/), which can have the title bars hidden.

Comment: The problem is that is not a program itself, so it requiers packages I don't have shipped with Ubuntu. I thought of that "-a" or "--app" option, but it's not compatible with all browsers, so it's not a viable option for what I'm looking for :/ Thank you though

Comment: I believe you are reinventing the wheel here. If you really need to do that, I think your best bet should be implementing an engine that's already coded (like Gecko, V8, etc). But you should be an experienced programmer for this alternative to have any chance to work. Anyway, the point is: Building a layout engine isn't trivial. M$ itself has had severe troubles doing it appropriately. lol

Comment: "PyXPCOM allows for communication between Python and XPCOM, such that a Python application can access XPCOM objects, and XPCOM can access any Python class that implements an XPCOM interface. With PyXPCOM, a developer can talk to XPCOM or **embed Gecko from a Python application**": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/PyXPCOM

Comment: "HulaHop is Gecko 1.9 (Firefox 3.0 core) web browser as a simple embeddable control with Python DOM access. It is a PyGTK Widget that you can use in your application to embed a web browser": http://wiki.laptop.org/go/HulaHop

Comment: Ok thanks for the informations, I'll upgrade my question knowing that `html` is NOT suitable for offline projects independent of a web-browser, since it requires a layout engine that can't be embedded simply with a commandline, and since lot of web-browser uses different engines.

Comment: How about trying a program that can read [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)? Will some thing like that work?

Comment: Markdown could be an option if it can read and display clickable URL's.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using QML and the Ubuntu SDK to build such screens? Here's a snippet of code that you could use to embed images, links and controls:

**demo.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    id: main
    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Column {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: units.gu(5)
        Text{
            text: "Hello"
        }

        Text{
            text: '<a href="http://askubuntu.com">askubuntu</a>'
            onLinkActivated: Qt.openUrlExternally(link)
        }

        Button {
            text: "button"
        }
    }
}
```

To run it, use qmlscene:

```
qmlscene ./demo.qml
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I had time to learn QML, I would also have time to learn Python :/